# Gnome-terminal not working properly with screen-256colors

Tags: gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, colors, tmux

Today I noticed I did not have 256 color support in Weechat. I decided this would be a quick fix. It isn't.

First thing I googled was how to test the color support in terminal. I have installed `colortest` on my local machine and when I run it it shows me 256 colors. However, when I run `echo $TERM` it kept showing me `xterm`.

Since I don't know the details about all these things I tried to configure it such that it matches up with every tutorial on the topic. They all say it should give me `screen-256colors`.

First thing I did was add this to my `.zshrc` file:

```
# If the $term variable is xterm, change it to 256 colors!
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then
    # No it isn't, it's gnome-terminal
    export TERM="xterm-256color"
fi
```

It says `xterm-256colors` instead of `screen-256colors`. That's okay, some tutorial told me to do that.

I start a new terminal, `echo $TERM` and I notice that it is indeed set. Fire up a `tmux` and see what that tells me when I type `echo $TERM`. It says `screen`. So that should show me `screen-256colors` for it to work properly in weechat. So next I tried to change the `xterm-256colors` in my `.zshrc` file to `screen-256colors` but when I do that, I get garbled output. See the screenshot.

[image]

So next I googled on how to change the variable for tmux. I found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux). It shows an option to configure tmux to use 256 colors. It is an option that is shown in almost all the tutorials.

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

So I tried it, yet it didnt change a thing. So I googled around some more and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux). Quote:

> Tmux is relatively picky about having a terminal set correctly. If you can, set the term value in gnome-terminal's configuration, not in your .bashrc. Failing that, surround those settings with a check for "`screen`" or "`screen-256color`" TERM, and don't reset them in that case.

Okay, so I understand that outside of `tmux` I should not use `screen*` values for `$TERM`. That's okay because it is set to `xterm-256colors`. Then it clearly states that I should not override the `$TERM` variable if it is set to `screen`. Which I have made sure of using the `if` test in my `.zshrc` file.

The thing that mainly confuses me is that 256 colors actually work in tmux. See the screenshot below. When I run `echo $TERM` inside tmux it shows `screen`. When I run `colortest-256` it shows me all colors properly. Yet, I *think* weechat bases itself on the `$TERM` variable to show colors. And because I run it inside `tmux` with `$TERM` set to `screen` it assumes I don't have 256 color support.

[image]

I am stumped on how to solve this issue. All I wanted were some colors in weechat :>

For completeness below are my two configuration files.

## .zshrc

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/home/christophe/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="flazz"
plugins=(git command-not-found common-aliases dircycle lein)


# Show dots for progress
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

##########
## PATH ##
##########

# Export directory if it exists.
#if [ -d "/usr/local/go/bin" ]; then
#    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
#fi

#############
## ALIASES ##
#############

alias randompass="< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c${1:-32};echo;"

############
## TWEAKS ##
############

# Disable shared history
setopt no_share_history


# Start existing or new tmux session each shell startup
#[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux attach -d
alias chat='tmux attach -dt weechat || tmux new -s weechat \; new-window htop'


# If the $term variable is xterm, change it to 256 colors!
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then
    # No it isn't, it's gnome-terminal
    export TERM="xterm-256color"
fi


######################
# User configuration #
######################

export PATH="/home/christophe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

## .tmux.conf

```
# 256 color support
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd like to confirm what you've already figured out, namely that directly under `gnome-terminal` (that is, outside of `tmux` or `screen`) you should set `TERM=xterm-256color`, whereas inside `tmux` or `screen` it should be set to `TERM=screen-256color`.

Apparently your `.zshrc` segment properly sets it for the shell that's run directly by gnome-terminal.

I'm not sure what needs to be put in `.tmux.conf`, I have solved it in my `.bashrc` similarly to your `.zshrc` fragment for xterm-256color. I also remove `TERMCAP` which is set by `screen` and causes some problems, but apparently `tmux` doesn't set it so it shouldn't make a difference for you.

```
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then
    export TERM=xterm-256color
fi
if [ "$TERM" = "screen" -o "$TERM" = "screen-256color" ]; then
    export TERM=screen-256color
    unset TERMCAP
fi
```

Does this solve the problem for you?

By the way, instead of this snippets, copying your `.tmux.conf` also sets this properly for me (on Vivid), so you're on the right track, it should work. Is there maybe something else sourced by your zsh (e.g. the global config, or oh-my-zsh) that reverts to the 8/16-color `TERM=screen`?

Comment: The update you gave me worked indeed! Everything is working excellent. Thank you for the feedback!